# Advanced Onion Router - install successfully and connected but my ip address did not change

Tags: tor

I have downloaded and installed Advanced Onion Router (AdvOR-0.3.0.20) on Windows 7 successfully, I have made it connected also. But after that, I see my ip address did not change, also I checked at check.torproject.org by both firefox and chrome return "not using tor".

Did I make anything wrong?

Regards,
Tin

Comment: Any reason you want to use that instead of the latest [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) for Windows?

Comment: No, I don't want to use Tor Browser because my purpose is build Crawler Tool by PHP to get products from other ecommerce sites so I need to install AdvOr in windowns to do this.

Comment: You also need to configure your browsers to proxy through AdvOR (default IP:Port = 127.0.0.1:9050).  Note that the software hasn't been updated in over a year so it is using older Tor code which may or may not be secure, but since it sounds like you are just using it to crawl from eCommerce sites there isn't much risk involved.  You can always download the latest Tor [Expert Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/download/download.html.en) for Windows to run the latest version of Tor and then configure PHP to connect through it using SOCKS.

Answer (score 2):

With the helps from the nice guys, I have found the solution with my case. 
I using PHP curl with Socks5 as the following:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
if (!empty($cookie)) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
// using TOR proxy
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "127.0.0.1:9050");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);

$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

It's success, because when I check $url = 'https://check.torproject.org', the content of html has a text: 
'Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor. '

Cheers!!

Comment: Hi, how can I do the same in .NET?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the download from this [link](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) at the Tor Project's website. That should get you running Tor properly on Windows without any trouble.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need Tor for Browsing. My purpose is build Crawler Tool by PHP to get products from other ecommerce sites so I need to install AdvOr in windowns to do this

Comment: @TínPhạm when you install the bundle it adds tor as a service and you can use it programatically in PHP, it is not just a browser but the entire software package that can run as a service from the command line or programmatically as well. I think you are missing that point because it is called Browser bundle.